# How do I find the associated the field and table bound to a control in C#?

Tags: c#, dataset, data-binding

I'm generating some code from a form object using reflection.  I want to iterate through all the controls on the form and output the field and table that each control is bound to.  Right now, I am able to output the data bound field for a control:

```
if ((control is Label) || (control is TextBox)) 
{
    if (control.DataBindings["Text"] != null) 
    {
        field = GetFieldDisplayName(control.DataBindings["Text"].BindingMemberInfo.BindingField);
    }
}
```

Getting the field is useless for me if I can't find its associated table programmatically.

Comment: I tried using the BindingMember and BindingPath but the yielded empty strings.

Comment: I'm getting the sense that this is purely one way.  Once the dataset is used to populate a datasource, the metadata is lost.  Boy, this makes it very difficult to generate code from using T4.